# Change go.js portId after creation

Tags: javascript, gojs

Extending the [Dynamic Ports](http://gojs.net/latest/samples/dynamicPorts.html) example, I created a node with a few ports in the leftArray. Each port is defined by a model like this:

```
{id: "port1"}
```

In the context menu of the port I let the user rename it. Currently, for testing purposes, right-clicking on a port opens a context-menu with a single button: "Rename". Clicking on "Rename" will change the id field of the model to "foo":

```
function(e, obj) { 
   obj.part.data.id = "foo";
}
```

The `id` field is bound to the `portId` property using:

```
new go.Binding("portId", "id").makeTwoWay()
```

Now when I create a link from another node to this renamed port and watch the model of my diagram using `myDiagram.model.toJson()` I see that the link appears to be connected to the corrent port but using the **old** `portId`.

What do I miss here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you did not modify the link data references to ports, so the Links continue to be routed to the same port GraphObjects.  But if you loaded the saved model, you'd see that the Links now seem to connect to other objects, depending on the port identifiers now being used.

I suggest that after you modify the port id that you iterate over the connected links and update the port references.  Something like this extra context menu button in the Dynamic Ports sample:

`makeButton("Rename port",
                   function(e, obj) {
                     var port = obj.part.adornedObject;
                     var node = port.part;
                     var data = port.data;
                     var oldpid = data.portId;
                     var linksinto = new go.List().addAll(node.findLinksInto(oldpid));
                     var linksoutof = new go.List().addAll(node.findLinksOutOf(oldpid));
                     myDiagram.startTransaction("portId");
                     // find a new unique port identifier
                     var newpid = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000).toString();
                     while (node.findPort(newpid) !== node.port) {
                       newpid = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000).toString();
                     }
                     // change port identifier
                     myDiagram.model.setDataProperty(data, "portId", newpid);
                     // change connected link references to ports
                     linksinto.each(function(l) {
                       myDiagram.model.setToPortIdForLinkData(l.data, newpid);
                     });
                     linksoutof.each(function(l) {
                       myDiagram.model.setFromPortIdForLinkData(l.data, newpid);
                     });
                     myDiagram.commitTransaction("portId");
                   }),`